# How do I DRY up this view with a concern or helper or something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dry, view-helpers

I have a `Post` that has file attachments, via Carrierwave.

In my view, depending on the type of attachment, I want a different icon to be displayed.

So this is what I have come up with, which works fine now but is quite unseemly and not DRY.

How do I streamline this and make it more Rails-y?

```
<% if post.file? %>
    <% if post.file.file.extension.downcase =~ /mp3|wav/ %>
        <i class="fa fa-file-audio-o"></i>
    <% elsif post.file.file.extension.downcase =~ /pdf/ %>
        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
    <% elsif post.file.file.extension.downcase =~ /txt/ %>
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
    <% elsif post.file.file.extension.downcase =~ /doc|docx/ %>
        <i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i>
    <% elsif post.file.file.extension.downcase =~ /xls|xlsx/ %>
        <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>
    <% elsif post.file.file.extension.downcase =~ /ppt|pptx/ %>
        <i class="fa fa-file-powerpoint-o"></i>
    <% elsif post.file.file.extension.downcase =~ /mp4|m4v|mov|avi|mkv/ %>
        <i class="fa fa-file-video-o"></i>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit 1**

I would also like to be able to easily detect what type of file the extension is, and then do some behavior to it. This icon version is just one application.

Another example is on my share buttons. Depending on the type of file attached, I want to add the name of the file included in the share title. So for instance:

My Twitter Share Icon would look something like this without this logic:

```
  <a class="btn btn-twitter" href='http://twitter.com/home?status=<%=u "#{post.title} - Read more at #{post_url(post)}" %>' title="Share on Twitter" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  </a>
```

With the logic:

```
<% if post.file? %> 
  <a class="btn btn-twitter" href='http://twitter.com/home?status=<%=u "#{post.title} (#{post.file.file.extension.upcase} Included) - Read more at #{post_url(post)}" %>' title="Share on Twitter" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  </a>
<% end %>
```

Is there a more elegant, Railsy way to approach this?

**Edit 2**

With @blelump's wonderful, elegant solution - which I love - I am trying this:

```
<i class='fa attached-<%= post.file.file.extension.downcase %>'></i>
```

Where in my `post.css.scss`, I have these rules:

```
.attached-mp3, .attached-wav {
    @extend .fa-file-audio-o;
}

.attached-pdf {
  @extend .fa-file-pdf-o;
}

.attached-txt {
    @extend .fa-file-text-o;
}
```

The issue is, the HTML being produced by this is this:

```
<i class="fa attached-txt"></i>
```

It doesn't seem to be calling the `@extend .fa-file-text-o`.

How do I fix this?

**Edit 3**

This is how my `post.css.scss` looks after @blelump's suggestions:

```
.field_report{
  width: 100%;
}

.field_report #report_box{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.attached-mp3, .attached-wav {
    @extend .fa-file-audio-o;
}

.attached-pdf {
  @extend .fa-file-pdf-o;
}

.attached-txt {
    @extend .fa-file-text-o;
}

.attached-doc, .attached-docx {
    @extend .fa-file-word-o;
}

.attached-xls, .attached-xlsx {
    @extend .fa-file-excel-o;
}

.attached-ppt, .attached-pptx {
    @extend .fa-file-powerpoint-o;
}

.attached-mp4, .attached-m4v, .attached-mov, .attached-mkv, .attached-avi {
    @extend .fa-file-video-o;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using LESS or SASS so CSS would rescue you here. For SASS, e.g.

```
.whatever-pdf {
  @extend .fa-file-pdf-o;
}
```

Because you are using FontAwesome icons, make sure these classes are declared within the `.scss` that includes the `@import FontAwesome` call. In your case, it seems to be the `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss`.

Then, within your view it rolls up into:

```
<i class="fa whatever-#{post.file.file.extension.downcase}"></i>
```

and that's all.

Edit 1:

Sample for `EN` locales:

```
# config/locales/en.yml:
en:
  posts: 
    file_has_been_included: "(your %{file} has been included)"
  extensions:
    pptx: powerpoint presentation
    # ...

#view:
  <a class="btn btn-twitter" href='http://twitter.com/home?status=<%=u "#{post.title} #{t("posts.file_has_been_included", file: t("extensions.#{post.file.file.extension.downcase}"))} - Read more at #{post_url(post)}" %>' title="Share on Twitter" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: So I would just create those rules for all extensions in my `.scss` file? Do you mind just editing this for all of my rules, so I can know exactly what my SASS file would look like? Thnx!

Comment: Yeah, of course there are another solutions, including adding some logic into your helper, but it is not necessary here. That's the fastest one for sure.

Comment: This is a nice elegant solution. The issue I am having is I want to do some more complex stuff. I just updated my question. Can you ammend your answer to also include an approach to that please? Thanks!

Comment: So eventually `#{post.title} (#{post.file.file.extension.upcase} Included) - ...` extends into `blah blah (PPTX included)`. Well, you can use your locales here, that would be more elegant. With `I18n` it would be `#{post.title} (#{t("something.something.pptx") } Included) - ...` which give `blah blah (your powerpoint presentation has been included) - ...` Better, isn't it?

Comment: That sounds good. Do you mind showing it in more detail in the answer please. Thanks! Edit: Including things like what I put in which `I18n` file, etc.

Comment: Perfect thanks! By any chance, do you have any experience with simple_form and country_select? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736875/how-do-i-get-the-country-select-gem-and-simple-form-to-work-from-scratch

Comment: Hey @blelump, I am having an issue with the first part of this answer. I just updated the question.

Comment: Does it compile properly? Look into your compiled `post.css` and check.  Is `.attached-pdf {  }` empty?

Comment: I don't even see `.attached-pdf` or any of the other rules in the compiled `post.css` in development. Should I enable something in my `development.rb` for it to compile? There are 2 other normal CSS rules in my `post.css.scss` that I see output in my `post.css`. Not sure if that matters, but I have never really used the `scss` functionality of my `sass` files aside from importing Bootstrap, before now.

Comment: I also edited my question to include my `post.css.scss` in its current state after your suggestion.

Comment: Since you want to load it only within your post actions, it won't work.  For SASS `@extend` directive your `.fa-file-...` classes are not visible and so your css is empty. You could include appropriate css containing these classes definitions into `post.css.scss`, but it will cause these classes will be loaded for post actions twice (first probably within your `app.css.scss` and second within `post.css.scss`).

Comment: You have two choices. Either put these `.attached-xls, .attached-xlsx` etc. definitions into scope (e.g. `app.css.scss` - yes, they'll be loaded everywhere then) containing `fa-` classes (so that there're visible for SASS `@extend` directive) or you need to move back to your first idea with tremendous `if else`/`case when` solution.

Comment: if I move it into my `app.css.scss` does it compile on EVERY request or just compiles once upon app deploy to Heroku? If it is compiled just once, and it just a matter of the styles being loaded in my `application.css` I don't mind that. But if it will be compiled on every single request (which I doubt, but I am just double checking) then that's obviously a no-no.

Comment: Btw, I just tried it and it still doesn't work. I am getting this error in my server.log: `WARNING on line 64 of /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss: ".attached-mp3" failed to @extend ".fa-file-audio-o".
  The selector ".fa-file-audio-o" was not found.
  This will be an error in future releases of Sass.
  Use "@extend .fa-file-audio-o !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.` Could it be that `.fa-file-audio-o` is a font-awesome icon. FontAwesome gets loaded in `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` after `application.css` is loaded. Could that be affecting it?

Comment: By the way....now that I am looking at my server.log, when I put it in my `post.css.scss` I am also seeing that error. So it isn't exclusive just to the `application.css.scss`.

Comment: SASS CSS compilation is a very sensitive process. You have to create some `file.css.scss`. Then, within that file, `@import right_name_for_fonts_awesome` and below yours css extensions. Did you get the idea? You can do it within `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` if that's the current place of `@import right_name_for_fonts_awesome`.

Comment: To address your first question, for production, they're compiled only once, during `assets:precompile` task.

Comment: ahh ok. That makes sense, What I did was just included those styles to my `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` which is where fontawesome was imported. Now that works. Great! Now to test the second part of the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote post.file.file.extension.downcase multiple times. You could declare it in a new variable

```
filename = post.file.file.extension.downcase
```

instead of if else statements you need to use case when statements

```
<% if post.file? %>
<% case filename %>
<% when filename =~ /mp3|wav/ %>
    <i class="fa fa-file-audio-o"></i>
<% when filename =~ /pdf/ %>
    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
<% when filename =~ /txt/ %>
    <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
<% when filename =~ /doc|docx/ %>
    <i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i>
<% when filename =~ /xls|xlsx/ %>
    <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>
<% when filename =~ /ppt|pptx/ %>
    <i class="fa fa-file-powerpoint-o"></i>
<% when filename =~ /mp4|m4v|mov|avi|mkv/ %>
    <i class="fa fa-file-video-o"></i>
<% end %>
```